# Error handling on sub

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

```
Private Sub CmdOpenInsp1201_Click()
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWkb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWks As Excel.Worksheet

Dim SQLCpt As String
Dim SQLLt As String

Dim rsCpt As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsLt As DAO.Recordset

SQLCpt = " SELECT [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.Position " & _
    " FROM TblMembers " & _
    " WHERE TblMembers.Position='Capt #1' "

SQLLt = " SELECT [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.Position " & _
    " FROM TblMembers " & _
    " WHERE TblMembers.Position='Lt #1' "

Set rsCpt = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLCpt, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rsLt = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLLt, dbOpenSnapshot)

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(CurrentProject.Path & "\Trk_Insp_1201_10_08_2016.xlsx")

Set xlWks = xlWkb.Sheets("Oct")

xlApp.Visible = True

With xlWks

Do While Not rsCpt.EOF
.Range("U42").Value = Nz(rsCpt!FullName, "")
rsCpt.MoveNext
Loop
End With

With xlWks

Do While Not rsLt.EOF
.Range("AA42").Value = Nz(rsLt!FullName, "")
rsLt.MoveNext
Loop
End With

SubExit:
On Error Resume Next

rsCpt.Close
rsLt.Close
Set rsCpt = Nothing
Set rsLt = Nothing

Exit Sub

SubError:

MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & "=" & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "An error occured"
 GoTo SubExit

    End Sub
```

This works and runs as expected, but I'm not sure of the error handling. I need the file open at the end of the sub, but I released the rs, is this needed? Is the the correct way to do this sub.

Would you do it differently?

Thanks for all the help thus far.

D

Answer (score 0):

That is a nice pattern but you forgot `On Error GoTo SubError`

```
Private Sub CmdOpenInsp1201_Click()
    On Error GoTo SubError
    ' Code
SubExit:
    On Error Resume Next

    rsCpt.Close
    rsLt.Close
    Set rsCpt = Nothing
    Set rsLt = Nothing

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub        
SubError:

    MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & "=" & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "An error occured"
    GoTo SubExit

End Sub
```

Comment: In the error handler, it should be `Resume SubExit` instead of `GoTo SubExit`.

Comment: @Andre that's interesting.  I didn't know that you could do that, however it doesn't work as intended.  Using `Resume SubExit` would just keep throwing the same error.   What the OP wants to do is get an error message for any error that is thrown before the objects get cleaned up.  After he receives the error message he wants the connection and recordsets closed and the sub to exit.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. An error handler block should end with `Resume <label>` to tell VBA that error handling is finished. `On Error Resume Next` in "SubExit" ensures that no further errors are thrown in the Cleanup part. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996697/difference-between-resume-and-goto-in-error-handling-block --- In "SubExit", `On Error GoTo 0` should be before `Exit Sub`.

Comment: @Andre thanks for your correction of the `On Error GoTo 0` position.  I still think that "it should be Resume SubExit instead of GoTo SubExit" will not work.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding it.  Could you please post an answer, so that I can analyz it?

Comment: I actually was surprised by what happened when I used `GoTo` in the error handler. Can you reproduce this? (I'm using Access 2010)

Comment: Do not forget `err.clear` before `resume` As a general rule, `goto` is frowned upon.

Comment: @Fionnuala: `Resume <Exit>` resets the Err object, so Err.Clear is not needed. See edit.

Comment: @Andre I missed your comment.  I'm not quite sure what you meant by "Can you reproduce this? ".  But like I said I like the pattern.  By the way, `On Error GoTo 0` really isn't needed before `Exit Sub` because when the subroutine ends so does  `On Error Resume Next`.  I am just in a habit of writing them together.

Comment: @ThomasInzina: I meant, if you run the sub from my answer with `GoTo TestErrorHandler_Exit`, do you get the error too (although it is after `On Error Resume Next`)? -- You are probably right about `On Error GoTo 0` being unnecessary. :)

Comment: On Error GoTo SubError  Would this go before or after the Dim statements?

Comment: It goes before the first line that might throw an error.  Personally, I place it at before the Dim if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

From our discussion in Thomas' answer. Surprisingly (I always use `Resume <Exit>` in error handlers) `GoTo SubExit` doesn't work for me. See comments.

This is my standard error handling (automatically inserted with a template in MZ-Tools):

```
Public Sub TestErrorHandler()

    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

On Error GoTo TestErrorHandler_Error

    ' Raise error
    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("NonExistingTable")
    ' This line will not be reached
    Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("OtherTable")

TestErrorHandler_Exit:
    ' This prints "0" because "Resume" clears the Err object
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description

    ' Only needed if something *can* go wrong in the "Exit" cleanup code
    On Error Resume Next

    ' The following line surprisingly raises error 91 "Object variable not set"
    ' when "GoTo TestErrorHandler_Exit" is used in the error handler!
    rs1.Close
    rs2.Close
    Set rs1 = Nothing
    Set rs2 = Nothing

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

TestErrorHandler_Error:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " in Modulex.TestErrorHandler:" & vbCrLf & _
           Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error"
    ' Finish error handling
    Resume TestErrorHandler_Exit
    ' Don't use this
    ' GoTo TestErrorHandler_Exit

End Sub
```