# Restart subroutine from an error handeler

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that notifies the user of an error with a message box and prompts the user to retry or cancel. What I would like the code to do is that if the user press "retry", vba will re-execute the code:

```
Sub CheckDate ()

Dim R as VbMsgBoxResult

On Error GoTo i

  Vba.Date = Range("A1").Value

Exit Sub

i:
Msgbox "An error has occurred, would you like to retry?", VbRetryCancel
If R = VbRetry Then ' **re-execute the code**

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
Sub CheckDate ()

Dim R as VbMsgBoxResult
m:
On Error GoTo i

  Vba.Date = Range("A1").Value

Exit Sub

i:
R = Msgbox( "An error has occurred, would you like to retry?", VbRetryCancel)
If R = VbRetry Then ' **re-execute the code**
    Err.Clear
    goto m:
End Sub
```

Comment: Just replaced goto m: with resume m: and it worked beautifully!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996697/difference-between-resume-and-goto-in-error-handling-block/2996735

Answer (score 0):

A couple recommendations, avoid using goto statements as they can lead to unorganized and hard to follow code. Using `IsDate` will allow VBA to check the date not letting an error happen. Using brackets can be a more concise way reference ranges You don't need to declare the response as a variable, just testing the result of the prompt works. And lastly, you can just recall the macro if the user wishes to retry.

```
Sub CheckDate ()
  if IsDate([A1].Value) then 
     Vba.Date = [A1].Value
  else
     if Msgbox("An error has occurred, would you like to retry?", VbRetryCancel) = VbRetry Then CheckDate
  end if 
End Sub
```